# Solve a ValueError

Tags: python, usbserial

I was looking a way to prove my USB-SERIAL port and I found this code:
http://www.digitalmihailo.com/usb-programming-with-python-on-linux-pyusb-version/, but I have a problem because when I run this program, then show me up this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "namefile.py", line 122 in <module>
     main()
   File "namefile.py", line 64, in main
     raise ValueError('Device not found')
ValueError: Device not found
```

I already install the PyUSB library, but the result does not change. Someone can help me with this little problem.

Thank you much  in advance.

Comment: Which usb-serial device are you tryng to access to? Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your example in Linux you need to load the [ACMtty module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/acm.txt) so you system makes a Serial USB device available for your user space.

As root and only if you have cdc-acm module compiled for your current kernel:

```
modprobe cdc-acm
```

Once this module is loaded and your device connected you should find a device named following this pattern: `/dev/ttyACM*`

You may have already installed the right user space tools and libraries but you also need to install the device.